# How do I make vim's visual lines indent correctly?

Tags: vim

When I press enter to create a logical line, vim keeps the indent of the previous line. However, for visual lines, since they are all one logical line, the new lines always start at first column. Is there a way to make new visual lines also auto-indent correctly?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you mean? What does the text look like after each keystroke (or group of keystrokes) and what would you like them to look like instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out with some additional searching around on SO and google. I used `set breakindent` and `set lbr` and it now produces the output that I want.